# Coordinate change to find a double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to evaluate this integral but I haven't found any good coordinate change. Any ideas?

[image: Any Ideas?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This integral requires a change of coordinates that somewhat resembles the polar coordinate system. The curve in the $y$-$z$ plane is the [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid) defined by $y^{2/3}+z^{2/3}=a^{2/3}$.

Converting to "polar" coordinates, you would set
$$\begin{cases}y=r\cos^3t\\[1ex]z=r\sin^3t\end{cases}$$
This yields the following Jacobian
$$\begin{align*}|J|&=\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}&\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\\[1ex]
\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial r}&\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial t}\end{vmatrix}\\[1ex]
&=\begin{vmatrix}\cos^3t&-3r\cos^2t\sin t\\[1ex]
\sin^3t&3r\sin^2t\cos t\end{vmatrix}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{3}{8}r(1-\cos4t)
\end{align*}$$
Since the limits to the integral are restricting the curve to lie in the first quadrant, you have $0\le t\le\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, and $r$ ranges from the origin to the curve, i.e. $0\le r\le a$.

So, the integral can be rewritten nicely:
$$\int_0^a\int_0^{(a^{2/3}-z^{2/3})^{3/2}}\left(a^{2/3}-y^{2/3}-z^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}\,dy\,dz=\frac{3}{8}\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^a\left(a^{2/3}-r^{2/3}\right)^{3/2}r(1-\cos4t)\,dr\,dt$$
Substituting $u=a^{2/3}-r^{2/3}$ will make short work of this integral.